# Match string and number with Regex to get the item and quantity from the string

Tags: ruby, regex

If for example, I have a list of strings like `'car 24'`, `'house'`, `'charlet bundle 54'`, `'chroma5one jenkin 4'`, `'m8rial imperial 54'`.
I would like to create a regex matcher, such that each of the items yields the corresponding results:

```
"car 24" #=> {item: 'car', quantity: 24}
"house" #=> {item: 'house', quantity: nil}
"charlet bundle 54" #=> {item: 'charlet bundle', quantity: 54}
"chroma5one jenkin 4" #=> {item: 'chroma5one jenkin', quantity: 4}
"m8rial imperial 50" #=> {item: 'm8rial imperial', quantity: 50}
"hou58" #=> {item: 'hou58', quantity: nil}
```

So far, I've tried several methods, but they don't seem to be working perfectly. e.g `(?<item>[[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*]+)(?<quantity>\d+)?`
One that seem to be working is: `(?<item>[[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*]+)(\D)(?<quantity>[\d]+)?` but it always require an empty space after each expression. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are they strings? If so, make it clear by writing them as string literals. Also, `=>` within the code formatting is confusing with hash literal. Change it to `# =>`.

Comment: What if you had `"hou58"`? What is the expected result? `{item: "hou", quantity: 58}`, `{item: "hou5", quantity: 8}`, `{item: "hou58", quantity: nil}`, or something else?

Comment: thanks @sawa. I just updated with the example of the `'hou58'`. it should return `{item: "hou58", quantity: nil}`

Comment: Try `s.scan(/\A([\w ]+?)(?:\s+(\d+))?\z/)`

Comment: @Wiktor, you may wish to tack on `.first` or `.flatten`.

Comment: I added this comment while I was on the go, on a mobile. I see OP has selected an answer  - no need posting my solution, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = 'm8rial imperial 54'   

string.scan(/\A([\w\W]+?)(?:\s+(\d+))?\z/).map { |(i,q)| {:item => i, :quantity => q} }
    #=> [{:item=>"m8rial imperial", :quantity=>"54"}]
```

Is this what you're looking for?

It splits your string into two parts if there is an integer (in string format) at the end of it. If there isn't then your entire string is placed under `item` and `nil` under `quantity`.

Answer (score 2):

```
R = /
    \s+     # match > 0 whitespace characters
    (?=\d)  # match a digit in a positive lookahead
    /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode

def make_hash(str)
  item, quantity = str.split(R)
  { item: item, quantity: quantity }
end

['car 24', 'house', 'charlet bundle 54', 'chroma5one jenkin 4',
 'm8rial imperial 54', 'hou58'].each { |s| puts make_hash(s) }
  # {:item=>"car", :quantity=>"24"}
  # {:item=>"house", :quantity=>nil}
  # {:item=>"charlet bundle", :quantity=>"54"}
  # {:item=>"chroma5one jenkin", :quantity=>"4"}
  # {:item=>"m8rial imperial", :quantity=>"54"}
  # {:item=>"hou58", :quantity=>nil}
```